# issue on database query to fetch data with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with a SELECT query.

```
    SELECT P.product_id
          , ( SELECT Category_id 
              FROM   Category C 
              WHERE  C.product_id = P.product_id) AS cat
    FROM Products P
```

This is supposed to pull the product_id from PRODUCTS and the category_id from CATEGORY. If the product is in multiple categories, I would like Categories field to return a list of those category_ids. The problem is a subquery will only return a single value. Does anyone know how to rewrite this?

Thanks!

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server you're having your problems with?

Comment: i need help with sql query logic to fetch list using subquery.. i will be using both mssql and mysql databse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this:

```
 SELECT P.product_id,  GROUP_CONCAT(PC.category_id SEPARATOR ', ')
   FROM Product_Category PC ,
        Products P
  WHERE PC.product_id = P.product_id
  GROUP BY P.product_id;
```

Check out [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db918/5).

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() is a MySQL function, so you'll have to use something like the STUFF() function in MS SQL. And I've always found using explicit JOIN statements to be more readable (no performance difference): FROM Product_Category PC INNER JOIN Products P ON PC.product_id = P.product_id.

Comment: @Shawn: there were both tags given, _mysql_ and _sql-server_ and I was just about to create a MS version when this answer got accepted by the OP.

Comment: @Trinimon I like GROUP_CONCAT(). It's something I've had to do for years in MS SQL. I know both functions have been in their flavors of SQL for a while, but they're still probably one of the more common operations I've seen. It's easy to get the relational data, but sometimes you just want another data list associated with a particular value. :-)

Comment: Just make sure to watch out for the separators. Commas have driven me crazy with character data type fields. :-S

Comment: @Shawn: can imagine of some issues and it can really be fun with localizations :D by the way: I retrieved my MS Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15ffdb/1

Answer (score 3):

A Sub-Query in Select MUST return a Scalar value, else it will error out. You can join two tables to get multiple values. or you can force sub-query to only return One value by using TOP clause.

Try

```
SELECT P.product_id
      ,PC.Category_id AS Categories
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Product_Category PC ON PC.product_id = P.product_id
```

OR

```
SELECT P.product_id
     , (SELECT TOP 1 Category_id 
        FROM Product_Category PC 
        WHERE PC.product_id = P.product_id
        ORDER BY PC.SomeColumn ) AS Categories
FROM Products P
```

Comment: i want to get one row for product id and multiple category id's from different table.

Comment: Them simply stick to the join query, you cannot use Sub-query in select with this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, some of which include:

```
select p.PRODUCT_ID, CATEGORY_ID
FROM products p
inner join product_category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
```

this will return a row for each product_Id and category_id combination.

Another option (Sql server 2005+ only)

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
STUFF((
  SELECT ','+ convert(varchar(50), pc.category_id) 
  FROM product_category pc 
  WHERE pc.product_id = p.product_id 
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
FROM products p
```

this will create a comma delimited list of your category IDs for each product id.  See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/303e7d/1

Looks like an answer has already been provided for accomplishing the mysql version

Comment: this will error out complaining about `ambiguous column product_id`

Comment: You don't need the WHERE in the STUFF(). That's done in the JOIN. Rather, you don't actually need the JOIN in the STUFF().

Comment: SELECT p.product_id,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ convert(varchar(50), pc.category_id)
               FROM product_category pc
              WHERE pc.product_id = p.product_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
 FROM products p

Comment: @Shawn thanks, updated my answer - that's definitely shorter and I'm sure more performant due to the unnecessary stuff - er... things.